# Print standard output of Process in event handler

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I have a console application which I am running as a process from my C# program.
I have made an event handler to be called when this process terminates.
How do I print the Standard output of this process inside the event handler. 
Basically, how do I access the properties of a process inside the event handler ?
My code looks like below.

```
public void myFunc()
{
.
.
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "myProgram.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
p.Start();
.
.
}

private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    Console.WriteLine("log: {0}", <what should be here?>);
}
```

I do not want to make the process object p as a field of the class.

Also, what is the use of `System.EventArgs e` field ? How can this be used ?

Comment: *I do not want to make the process object p as a field of the class.* -- Why not?

Comment: @DaveShaw: There's no reason to do that.  The event handler already will post back the process object as the `sender` parameter.  No reason to keep that information in a redundant place.

Comment: @DaveShaw, I did not want to do that because in my implementation, I have an array of processes. And if I make that a field of this class, things get a little complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your event handler

```
object sender
```

is the Process object (that is a pretty common pattern by the way throughout the .NET Framework)

```
Process originalProcess = sender as Process;
Console.WriteLine("log: {0}", originalProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Note also that you have to set:

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

to use IO redirection in your Process.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Process pro = sender as Process; 
    string output = pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine("log: {0}", output);
}
```

*Standart output* is nothing else then [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx).

Comment: what is **p** in `myProcess_Exited` ?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to capture it in a closure:

```
public void myFunc()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "myProgram.exe";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Exited += new EventHandler((sender, args) => processExited(p));
    p.Start();
}

private void processExited(Process p)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.ExitTime);
}
```